Did I lose crypto by accidentally sending to my own wallet on USDC (sol)
I was trying to send USDC (SPL) on the solana network, and I accidentally sent crypto back to my own wallet without realizing. I thought I copied my friend's wallet address but I guess it didn't process on my phone, so it pasted my own USDC (SPL) address which was still in the clipboard.
I see the outbound transaction to myself here:

https://solscan.io/tx/37iraAqoD3hdGrJUxU87rhJwig4ARGBcaGLkWKFie5bLZNDPHLSqQCssX1eFV3BQWZn4eFErS5oN8kqe1q4zoLMs
However I don't see any receive for this, just the debit. (Both in Trust Wallet, which was used, as well as on solscan.io). Is this money lost or will it eventually show up in my wallet? The transaction says it's completed but my balance doesn't reflect it being received.

Summary: no money was lost. It just looks like it based only on the single transaction in the scanners.
It seems like this was properly treated as a "self transfer". I don't know why the wallets and scanners only show a single transaction, but I don't believe money was lost.
I sent myself $1 from my own wallet to test. I see it again only as an outbound transfer listed but I confirmed my balance did not actually deplete. It still has the dollar.
https://solscan.io/tx/KafXjtuQqVVrB7FSdWFV77a6P8WPaA7R1zPYRoJgeGdAagSdJ1qgiERKsZEy46bsWt9axHvRGe7WCozbP5K8ybz
